# Unable to select value from dropdown menu?

Tags: php

I have this dropdown menu and I want people to be able to add a new category if they do not find it on the menu, but I want the form hidden unless they select 'Outro'. If they do then it should be displayed. but I haven't been able to make it change depending on the answer. What am I doing wrong?

here's the code:

```
 echo '<form name="display_Info" action="" method="post">';
 echo '<select name="selected_Category" id="selected_Category">';
 echo'<option value="0" label="coyvalue" selected="selected"> Escolha sua Categoria </option>';

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($BC_SQLselect_Query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $BC_ID = $row['BC_ID'];
        $BC_Categories = $row['BC_Categories'];
        echo '<option value"'.$BC_ID.'">'.$BC_Categories.'</option>';
 }

 mysqli_free_result($BC_SQLselect_Query);
 $selected_Category = $_POST['selected_Category'];
 echo '</select></br>';
 echo'</form>';

 if ($selected_Category !== 'Outro'){
        $BC_New_Category = $row['BC_Categories'];
        echo'Adicione Nova Categoria: </br>
            <input type="text" name="BC_New_Category" value="'.$BC_New_Category.'"/>';
        echo '<option value"'.$BC_ID.'">'.$BC_New_Category.'</option>';
        $BC_Category_Update = 'INSERT INTO business_categories(BC_Categories) VALUES ('.$BC_New_Category.')';
 } else {
        echo'nothing';
 }
```

Comment: Please fix the outlining a bit man this sucks to read rofl

Comment: are you expecting the form to display immediately when they make a selection? then you'll have to look into a js solution, rather than PHP, with PHP you can only get it done after a reload or post request sent...

Comment: At a quick glance, you forgot an equal sign `<option value"'.$BC_ID.'">` for a few of them. Which would render something like `<option value"id_number_1">` rendering invalid.

Comment: you need to use js or jquery for this job

Comment: does `option` have a `label` attribute at all...?

Comment: Plus, this `</br>` should read as `<br/>`, won't fix your code but it is proper syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this:

```
<option value="0" label="coyvalue" selected="selected"> Escolha sua Categoria </option>
```

You basically "hardcode" the `selected` value to be `0`, so it will never be equal to 'Outro'.

**Edited:** just for the sake of a complete answer, and full credit goes to @Fred-ii- who pointed this out in his comment, you should probably also replace this...

```
echo '<option value"'.$BC_ID.'">'. /*...*/ .';
```

with this...

```
echo '<option value="'.$BC_ID.'">'. /*...*/ .';
```

You were missing an equial sign after the `value` attribute.